# Jquery ajax code is going in error part

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have called an javascript function, Inside which I am using an ajax. But I have no idea why it is always going in `else` part. Below is the code

```
function BindHTMLTable() {
        var structureName = $('#<%=ddlFacilityId.ClientID %>').val();
        var facilityID = $('#<%=ddlFacilityId.ClientID %> :selected').text();

        $.ajax({
            url: "UBRDashboard.aspx/GETSTRUCTUREINFO",
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            data: JSON.stringify({ facilityID: facilityID, structureName: structureName }),
            async: true,
            processData: false,
            cache: false,
            success: function (r) {
                alert('page loaded');
            },
            error: function (xhr) {
                alert('Error while selecting list..!!');
            }
        })
    }
```

And the server side function

```
public static string GETSTRUCTUREINFO(string facilityID, string structureName)
    {
        string strStructure = "";
        try
        {
            DataTable dtStructureInfo = CommonDB.GET_STRUCTURE_DETAILS(facilityID, structureName);                
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {                
            throw ex;
        }
        return strStructure;
    }
```

Comment: with "else" part you mean in "error" callback of the ajax call?

Comment: @OluwafemiSule: sorry my mistake. i mean `error` part.

Comment: @Sycraw: sorry my mistake. i mean error part

Comment: Are you sure that server side doesn't go in error? Have you debugged it?

Comment: @MichalHainc: i get `xhr` as `[object object]`

Comment: @Sycraw: it's not taking me to server side function, before that only i get error

Comment: I do not see any decorations with the server side function. Is it implemented correctly? What it is it? Is it a web page method?

Comment: @xxxmatko: yes its a webmethod, i guess i forgot to add that. Good catch man

Comment: Add a breakpoint to your control, see the incoming data and see where the direction of your code flow is headed to

Comment: Did you add [HttpPost] attribute your method?

Comment: guys, by adding `webMethod` now its working as required. catched by @xxxmatko. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this decoration to your server side method

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod()]
```

Than you can create the resulting html table like this:

```js
$("button").click(function() {
  var data = [
   {"RJ_NETWORK_ENTITY_ID":"INUESTPRISMLTW0001ENBRRH003","EQUIPMENT_NAME":"RAN:RR::577569"},
   {"RJ_NETWORK_ENTITY_ID":"INUESTPRISMLTW0001ENBRRH002","EQUIPMENT_NAME":"RAN:RRU::577571"}
  ];

  // Just get handle for the existing table
  var table = $("#tblData");

 // Clear table
  table.empty();

  // Create header row
  var header = $("<tr><th>RJ Network Entity ID</th><th>Equipment Name</th></tr>");
  table.append(header);

  // Create rows
  data.forEach(function(dataRow) {
    var tr = $("<tr>");
    $.each(dataRow, function(key,value) {
      tr.append("<td>" + value + "</td>");
    });
    table.append(tr);
  });
});
```

```css
table, td, th {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tblData"></table>

<button>
fill table
</button>
```

Comment: perfect catch, it was missing in my server side code

Comment: Your welcome, so please mark this as an answer for other.

Comment: it says u can mark answer after 5 mins, i m waiting for it. if you dont mind can i ask one more thing here ?

Comment: Yes you can, just ask.

Comment: I am bringing the data in a datatable which consist of two columns , so I want to display that data in a `table` format dynamically after `success` .. any way to do this ?

Comment: You can return the data in JSON format and create html table in your javascript success callback. Or you can create the html table right in your server side method and return the whole html. But the JSON is better way.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153861/discussion-between-vvvv-and-xxxmatko).